# Uploading image to Amazon S3 with Node.js results in a small transparent square

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64

I am uploading a image to Amazon S3 bucket but when it arrives there, it's a small transparent square, in the future I will use a Front-end application and the file will be uploaded from user computer.

I am using an ReGex for transforming to base64, but when it arrives at the S3 Bucket it is a small square as you can see here:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/node-str-img-bucket/v0u2HHYolOYwXprSeU73v.jpg

My original file URL that I am using for testing upload you can see [clicking here](https://pastebin.com/raw/AA84Jewt).

Here is my JavaScript uploading process:

```
AWS.config.update(config.AWS);
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const bucket = 'node-str-img-bucket';

let filename = nanoid().toString() + '.jpg';
let rawdata = req.body.image;
let matches = rawdata.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
let type = matches[1];
let buffer = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

let params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: filename,
    Body: rawdata,
    ContentType: type,
    ACL: 'public-read'
};

await s3.upload(params, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Anything you can help me would be nice.

Comment: do you have a script for reverting the data back from base64 on the s3? because it seems that the base64 data is saved on the s3 server instead of your image data

Comment: No, I don't have, should I look for that?

Comment: you could try it, or you could try to upload regular image, not base64 encoded image

Comment: or try change your script from `Body: rawdata` to `Body: buffer`

Answer (score 1):

use `putObject` rather than `upload`

```
await s3.putObject(params, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

also change the `contentType` & `Encoding` as:

```
let params = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: filename,
  Body: rawdata,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
  ACL: 'public-read'
};
```

Comment: Gonna try that by the morning, but my user will be able to upload PNG file format too, so I would like to keep the type dynamic.

Comment: @CassianoMontanari yes you can set the type dynamic, I have just added `image/jpeg` as example :)

Comment: @CassianoMontanari any luck?

Comment: Could not test yet, it's my side project, as soon I test, gonna let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: @CassianoMontanari you better try it by now. You wasted his time.

Comment: Sorry @ino I can’t anymore

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issues and tried to solve it for hours. Seems like the problem is coming from the API Gateway configuration. If you are using the console,go to the settings and add to the `Binary Media Types */* or using open api add` x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types: [ "*/*" ]` at the top of the file

Answer (score 1):

req.files[0] will have following data

{
fieldname: 'img',
originalname: 'Annotation 2021-01-11 095535.png',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/png',
buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 2d 00 00 01 a2 08 06 00 00 00 9b 3e 85 60 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 04 ... 38012 more bytes>,
size: 38062
}

now try this -

```
const { originalname, buffer, encoding, mimetype } = req.files[0]
s3.upload ({Bucket: 'somebucket',
        Key: originalname, 
        Body: buffer,
        ContentEncoding: encoding,
        ContentType: mimetype,
    },function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.log("Error", err);
     } if (data) {
       console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
     }
   })
```

Comment: Impossible to try your suggestion, it's an 2 years and 9 months old issue.

Comment: Added in setting of AWS apigateway Binary Media type set as */* and it worked.